# keyboard layout: change super key (windows key) to behave differently [WINDOWS]

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

How does one Map the Super/Windows Key to a diffrent key or Disable it all together.

Xmodemap -e does it in Linux.

How do you edit these keys in windows?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/